# Using Ionic toggle inside a form

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, toggle

Using Angular and Ionic, how can I use Ionic's toggle (as an input) inside of a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it only with assign a ng-model.

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="option.isSelected" toggle-class="toggle-calm">
  {{option.title}}
</ion-toggle>
```

If you are iterating over a Model List, you can try something like this:

```
<ion-toggle ng-repeat="option in options" ng-model="option.isSelected" toggle-class="toggle-calm" >
  {{option.title}}
</ion-toggle>
```

Answer (score 2):

For ionic 2 the recomended syntax is:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Name of the toggle</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle checked="true"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

If you want to access the status of the toggle you need to bind it to a member of your controller. In angular 2 the syntax for two-way binding is this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Name of the toggle</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggleStatus" checked="true"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

From your controller the variable `this.toggleStatus` will be a boolean that you can read to get user input, or change to set the toggle status on the screen.